# PHP can't delete MS Access table row

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple MS Access database to insert a single-column row. Here is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bell Sistemas - Site de Atividades Teste em PHP</title>
</head>
<?php
    include "session.php";
    include "header.php";
    include "connectSQL.php";

echo "<br><form action='' method='POST'><table align='center'>
<tr><th align='left'>Atividade: <br><input type='text' name='activity'></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left'><input type='submit' name='Cadastrar2' value='Cadastrar'></th></tr></table></form>";

$activity = $_POST['activity'];

if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar2'])) {
    if($activity==''){
        echo "O campo está vazio.";
    }
    else{
        $sql = "Insert Into Atividades(Atividade) VALUES('$activity')";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        echo "Atividade inserida.";
    //header("Location: ./menu.php"); /* Redirect browser */
    //exit();
    }}
?>

<?php
$sql  = "SELECT CdAtividade, Atividade FROM Atividades ORDER BY Atividade";

$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "\n<hr>";
echo "<table align='center'><tr><th align='left'>Atividade</th></tr>";
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr><td align='left' width='250'>".$row['Atividade']."</td><td width='75'>Editar</td><td><a href='delete_atividade.php?CdAtividade=".$row['CdAtividade']."'>Excluir</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<?php
include "footer.php";
include "tableConfig.php";
?>

</body>
    </html>
```

And I configured the delete_atividade.php like this:

```
<?php
 // connect to the database
 include "session.php";
 include "connectSQL.php";

 // get id value
 $cdatividade = $row['CdAtividade'];

 // delete the entry
 $sql  = "DELETE FROM Atividades WHERE CdAtividade='$cdatividade'";
 $result = $db->query($sql);

 // redirect back to the view page
 if($result){
 header("Location: atividades.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 header("Location: atividades.php");
 }

?>
```

However, when I click to delete a row, it does not delete it. Have I forgot something?

I appreciate anyone who can help me.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will be the final solution, but for starters:

```
$cdatividade = $row['CdAtividade'];
```

The `$row` variable doesn't exist in this file. You're passing on the query string, so it should be:

```
$cdatividade = $_GET['CdAtividade'];
```

Also, generally speaking for numeric values it's not necessary to surround in quotes, so your current delete statement:

```
$sql  = "DELETE FROM Atividades WHERE CdAtividade='$cdatividade'";
```

...could be rewritten as:

```
$sql  = "DELETE FROM Atividades WHERE CdAtividade=$cdatividade";
```

Finally, it's worth noting as **Marc B** did that your current query is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks like the following:

http://yourdomain.com/delete_atividade.php?CdAtividade=0;DROP TABLE Atividade;

Will result in your SQL looking like this:

```
DELETE FROM Atividades WHERE CdAtividade=0;DROP TABLE Atividades;
```

When executed, your table will be dropped, and that's no fun.